# Problem with electric potential - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

What I want to do is to create a simple contour plot from point charges at different coordinates and strengths with matplotlib.

I copied the code from this blog post: https://pythonmatplotlibtips.blogspot.com/2017/12/draw-beautiful-electric-field-lines.html and it works beautifully.

However, the color at the location of the point charges do not seems to scale properly. There is no different in color for point at coordinate (8,5) with a charge of +0.5 and point at coordinate (16,4.5) with a charge of +8.0 for instance. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as I am a novice in both physic and coding. Is there a way to force the colors to match the scaling of the color bar?[the radius scale with the magnitude of the charge but not the color...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGqqg.jpg)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode as ode
from matplotlib import cm
from itertools import product

class charge:
    def __init__(self, q, pos):
        self.q=q
        self.pos=pos
 
def E_point_charge(q, a, x, y):
    return q*(x-a[0])/((x-a[0])**2+(y-a[1])**2)**(1.5), \
        q*(y-a[1])/((x-a[0])**2+(y-a[1])**2)**(1.5)
 
def E_total(x, y, charges):
    Ex, Ey=0, 0
    for C in charges:
        E=E_point_charge(C.q, C.pos, x, y)
        Ex=Ex+E[0]
        Ey=Ey+E[1]
    return [ Ex, Ey ]

def E_dir(t, y, charges):
    Ex, Ey=E_total(y[0], y[1], charges)
    n=np.sqrt(Ex**2+Ey*Ey)
    return [Ex/n, Ey/n]

def V_point_charge(q, a, x, y):
    return q/((x-a[0])**2+(y-a[1])**2)**(0.5)

def V_total(x, y, charges):
    V=0
    for C in charges:
        Vp=V_point_charge(C.q, C.pos, x, y)
        V = V+Vp
    return V

#define graph boundary
x0 = 0
x1 = 20
y0 = 0
y1 = 8

# charges and positions
charges=[ charge(-0.5, [10, 4]), 
         charge(-1, [3, 3]), 
         charge(0.5, [8, 5]), 
         charge(-2, [1.5, 1.5]),
         charge(0.5,[14,5]),
         charge(8,[16,4.5])]

qq = []
for c in charges:
    qq.append(c.q)
qq.sort()
q0 = qq[0]
q1 = qq[-1]

# calculate electric potential
vvs = []
xxs = []
yys = []
numcalcv = 300
for xx,yy in product(np.linspace(x0,x1,numcalcv),np.linspace(y0,y1,numcalcv)):
    xxs.append(xx)
    yys.append(yy)
    vvs.append(V_total(xx,yy,charges))
xxs = np.array(xxs)
yys = np.array(yys)
vvs = np.array(vvs)

#output chart
# plot electric potential
clim0,clim1 = q0,q1
vvs[np.where(vvs<clim0)] = clim0*0.999999 # to avoid error
vvs[np.where(vvs>clim1)] = clim1*0.999999 # to avoid error

#field color
plt.tricontourf(xxs,yys,vvs,100,cmap=cm.jet)

#color scale
cbar = plt.colorbar()

#chart bound
plt.axis('tight')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim(x0,x1)
plt.ylim(y0,y1)
#plt.savefig('out22.jpg',dpi = 300)
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you attach your image?

Comment: sorry image is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGqqg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a while I figured out what the problem was, so might as well post an update on what I found. Point charge for each coordinate created by np.linspace is calculated by charge/distance^2 function. The problem arises when the distance to the charge is too small, so the calculated point charge approaches infinity. The solution I came up with is to replace the distance value with a minimum value (line spacing) when the distance is too small.

My code now look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode as ode
from matplotlib import cm
from itertools import product

class charge:
    def __init__(self, q, pos):
        self.q=q
        self.pos=pos
        
def V_point_charge(q, a, x, y, xinc, yinc):
    xx = (x-a[0])**2
    yy = (y-a[1])**2
    if xx < xinc:
        xx = xinc
    if yy < yinc:
        yy = yinc
    return q/((xx)+(yy))**(0.5)

def V_total(x, y, charges,xinc,yinc):
    V=0
    for C in charges:
        Vp=V_point_charge(C.q, C.pos, x, y, xinc,yinc)
        V = V+Vp
    return V

#define graph boundary
x0 = 0
x1 = 20
y0 = 0
y1 = 8



# charges and positions (charge, [x,y])
charges=[ charge(-0.5, [10, 4]), 
         charge(-1, [3, 3]), 
         charge(0.5, [8, 5]), 
         charge(-10, [1.5, 1.5]),
         charge(2,[14,5]),
         charge(8,[16,4.5])]

qq = []
for c in charges:
    qq.append(c.q)
qq.sort()
q0 = qq[0]
q1 = qq[-1]

# calculate electric potential
vvs = []
xxs = []
yys = []
numcalcv = 300
xinc = np.sqrt((x1-x0)**2)/(numcalcv-1)
yinc = np.sqrt((y1-y0)**2)/(numcalcv-1)
for xx,yy in product(np.linspace(x0,x1,numcalcv),np.linspace(y0,y1,numcalcv)):
    xxs.append(xx)
    yys.append(yy)
    vvs.append(V_total(xx,yy,charges,xinc,yinc))
xxs = np.array(xxs)
yys = np.array(yys)
vvs = np.array(vvs)

#output chart

# plot electric potential
clim0,clim1 = q0,q1
vvs[np.where(vvs<clim0)] = clim0*0.999999 # to avoid error
vvs[np.where(vvs>clim1)] = clim1*0.999999 # to avoid error

#field contour
#plt.tricontour(xxs,yys,vvs,10,colors="0.3")

#field color
plt.tricontourf(xxs,yys,vvs,100,cmap=cm.jet)


#chart bound
plt.axis('tight')
plt.xlim(x0,x1)
plt.ylim(y0,y1)

#color scale
cbar = plt.colorbar()

#save image
plt.axis('equal')
#plt.axis('off')
#plt.savefig('out6.jpg',dpi = 300, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)


plt.show()
```

Comment: output image look like this now: https://imgur.com/a/1TqCFiI